# Prompt list via HELP prompt in Windows 7 command prompt

Tags: windows-7, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do certain commands not show up when you type “help” in cmd.exe?](https://superuser.com/questions/62220/why-do-certain-commands-not-show-up-when-you-type-help-in-cmd-exe)

If I enter `HELP` in the Windows 7 command prompt, it will give me a substantial list of command prompts. But, this list doesn't appear to cover every prompt that can be entered in the Windows 7 command prompt. For example, it does not have `IPCONFIG`, or `NSLOOKUP`, or many others.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: I am trying to VTC as dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/62220/why-do-certain-commands-not-show-up-when-you-type-help-in-cmd-exe or http://superuser.com/questions/485009/command-to-see-all-windows-commands, but it's not allowing me to do so (even though first one has an upvoted and accepted answer). I do *not* like this stupid change. Off to rant in meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HELP` only shows built-in commands. All executables in your `%PATH%` can be called, too. To see your path, try `echo %PATH%`.

If you want to know where an executable that you can execute (such as `NSLOOKUP`) is, check out [Is there an equivalent of 'which' on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/304319/309483).

To see all executables in your `%PATH%`, search all the directories in it for files having one of your [PATHEXT](http://environmentvariables.org/PathExt)'s.

Comment: Ah, you mean "internal," right? I see now.